# Let $p$ be prime and $a, b$ be integers such that $p \nmid a$. Prove that if $p^2 \mid ab$, then $p^2 \mid b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

For my cryptology class, we're asked to prove this statement:

> Let $p$ be prime and $a, b$ be integers such that $p \nmid a$. Prove that if $p^2 \mid ab$, then $p^2 \mid b$.

I'm not sure where to even begin with this proof. I think it must rely on some property of $p$ as a prime number since the next question was to give a counterexample to show it's not necessarily true for composite $p$, but since $p^2$ is no longer a prime number (since it would be divisible by at least 1, itself, and $p$), I'm not sure where this comes in. I thought to try the definition of divisibility and say there exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p^2 k = ab$, but I don't see where to go from there. Since $p^2$ isn't prime, I can't use that $p \mid ab \implies p \mid m \,\text{or}\, p \mid n$.

**Edited to add**: we have covered the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but I don't see how to apply that either. Perhaps to say that $k$ is either a prime or a product of primes? I'm not sure whether that produces any progress.

Any hints as to first steps I could take or a sketch of the proof would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: Can you use the fact that every positive integer can uniquely (up to order) be written as a product of primes? That's certainly the easiest way to go about it, though sometimes that theorem ("the fundamental theorem of arithmetic") doesn't get introduced quickly in a class or is otherwise avoided (...but it's a pretty powerful tool when you're just proving things in general) - and you don't need the full power of that here, it's just a bit more work.